# Where can I get 'classic' Lego heads from?

Tags: minifigures, shopping

The new heads with expressions are all well and good, but I for one prefer the expressionless 'classic' faces.

Are they available anywhere?

Comment: I think http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/220/whats-the-most-cost-effective-and-efficient-way-to-buy-bricks is going to be our single canonical "Here's how you find bricks to buy" question.

Answer (score 13):

The well known, smiling, gender-neutral multifigure head can be bought on auction sites like [Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3626bp01).

The classic faces are still in production now and are on the minifig or every set in the modular series. ([The Grand Emporium](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=10211-1) alone has seven of these heads) As well as other modern classics like the carousel, winter toy shop and town plan.

Up to five of these heads can be found in most editions of the Vintage Minifigure Collection.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

[bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com) has links to most lego bricks, new as old.

Something like [this head](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3626bp01)?

Comment: And if you want to know in which sets it's still in use, you can then use the ["In Sets" search feature](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3626bp01&in=S&viewSum=Y) and browse by year. It's still in use nowadays (But it's bound to change from hollow to recessed stud some day, I suppose)