# Where can I find LEGO technic pieces?

Tags: technic, shopping

I love the design by me software, but there are too few LEGO Technic pieces.

Do you know somes places (in Europe) where I can find LEGO Technic pieces without buying sets ?

Comment: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/220/whats-the-most-cost-effective-and-efficient-way-to-buy-bricks covers all bricks, and so Technic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Directly from LEGO:

- [Pick a brick](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Pick-A-Brick-ByTheme)

Third party:

- [bricklink.com](http://www.bricklink.com/)

bricklink is cheaper in most cases, on both you can choose and buy only the pieces you really need.

Answer (score 2):

I'll pretend I didn't read the "without bying sets" part.

**Go buy some!**

Seriously, this is the simplest way to acquire good packs of assorted Technic parts, and if you haven't got much experience with Technic yet, building the models is a great way to learn.

Of course, some models are better than others in terms of assortment provided , but I don't know for sure what's the best value for money at the moment. Whether you want electric or pneumatic parts will play a role, as will possible clearances in your area.

If you can find a LEGO education reseller, they also [carry Technic parts packs](http://www.legoeducation.us/eng/categories/products/elementary/_/characteristics/productType~LEGO%20Spare%20Parts), but BrickLink is probably going to be cheaper anyway (you can filter by country, too — buying from someone in your country is usually easier and cheaper).

Comment: some times i just need an extra worm or motor, i will not buy a set just for 1 or tow pieces

Comment: My mistake, I was under the impression you wanted to buy more parts. So yes, for spare parts, oezi's [answer](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/354) is better. I maintain that LEGO education could be interesting (but in Europe you'd have to find a resller first and it'd usually be too expensive), and eBay may have good surprises, but Bricklink is the way to go when you know what you're after. One last thing on motors: LEGO also sells them individually in the [Power Functions](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Power-Functions-ByTheme) section instead of the pick-a-brick one.