# How can I minimize the number of merchants for given set of requested bricks?

Tags: shopping, bricklink

This question should be answered in Bricklink FAQ, but I didn't find answer there.

I'm a casual Lego hobbyist, I have a few sets with random pieces missing, about two dozens of them. Some are truly rare. What is the best way to find smallest group of sellers having (collectively) all required bricks? It will minimize cost of sending packages overseas.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can [create a wishlist](http://www.bricklink.com/wantedAdd.asp), then [view sellers ordered by the number of lots](http://www.bricklink.com/wantedShop.asp) they have of the items in that wishlist.  That should give you a good starting point.

Comment: Number of *unique* lots, otherwise you'll find that a lot of sellers have multiple listings of the same item (often at the same price) because they keep second hand lots together.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create a wanted list. View the largest sellers in your country, go to their stores and browse by your wanted list. After going through 2 or 3 stores, you will find bricks less common still on the list. You'll have to browse stores selling that brick to get them.

Comment: My experience is that finding the largest sellers in any country aren't necessarily the best to use. If you have a wanted list, use the "sort by parts (unique)" page.

Comment: Speaking from my experience, this is the technique I used to limit my creation to no more than 5 stores. But yes, if you need specific unique parts, maybe that's not the best idea.

Comment: Yeah, it depends on what you want. If they're readily available then biggest shop is likely to work ok. But for any parts that aren't common the big shops are unlikely to have them. I buy mostly Technic parts and even the larger Technic-specific sellers tend not to have less common parts.